# Azure AD unable to create a default tenant

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I created an Azure account using my personal Microsoft account. After I log into my Azure portal there should be a default directory associated but there is none and when I try to create one it always says "Already in use by another directory.".

I always thought a default one is create for me but that doesn't look like the case anymore.

Is this normal?

Comment: Try searchhing for "tenant" in the  search bar, and select "Tenant Properties". Do you not see your default directory there?

Comment: no looks like you at least need one azure subscription. I can see the tenant now after creating an azure subscription. Previously you used to get default directory without even having an azure subscription. I can understand the change but not sure if it just happened to me or across the board.

Comment: Based on the Repro, With No Subscription associated, I am able to find the default directory and also able to create one, without any issues.
We do not find any changes on structure and procedure, Please try recreating the the account. [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9DSAU.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9DSAU.png) [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLPmm.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLPmm.png) [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pk0xV.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pk0xV.png)